# esp8266 ip address issues

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-ide, c

I have android studio app and arduino codes they are connected to each other using esp8266
but it works only on one network when I use another network it doesn't recognise it's ip address instead it gives 0.0.0.0
[image]
Only this worked

[image]

```
 #include <LCD5110_Graph.h>
    #include <Adafruit_MLX90614.h>

    #define DEVICE_ID "Monitor1"

    #define DEBUG true
    #define REQ_CODE_ACK 1
    #define REQ_CODE_VALUES 2

    //84w * 48h
    LCD5110 myGLCD(8,9,10,12,11);
    extern uint8_t SmallFont[];   //8h * 6w font

    Adafruit_MLX90614 mlx = Adafruit_MLX90614();
    int pinLM35 = A0;         //Pin A0 is for LM35
    int fsrAnalogPin = A2;    //Pin A2 is for force sensor
    int blinkPin = 13;        // Pin 13 is the on-board LED

  String mSSID = "LibyaADSL-9a86";    //initial ssid and password
  String mPASS = "BYRTPCRJAHPWQ";

    //http request code
    int service_code;        


    //wifi listen variables
    String wifiBuf = "";        
    char character;
    int connectionId = 0 ;

    //sensor values
    float sensor_mlx, sensor_heart, sensor_lm35;
    int sensor_force;

    void setup() {
      //init LCD  
      myGLCD.InitLCD();
      myGLCD.setFont(SmallFont);
      randomSeed(analogRead(7));

      //init MLX90614
      mlx.begin();

      //init serial
      Serial.begin(115200);           //Arduino-PC
      Serial3.begin(115200);          //Arduino-ESP8266\

      //init esp8266
      init8266(); 

      pinMode(blinkPin,OUTPUT);         // pin that will blink to your heartbeat!

      delay(200);
    }

    //init esp8266
    void init8266()
    {    
        Serial.println("Init ESP...");
        String stationConCmd = make8266InitCommand();

        sendCommand("AT+RST\r\n",2000,DEBUG);       // reset module
        sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n",1000,DEBUG);  // configure as access point    
       // sendCommand("AT+CWDHCP=1,1\r\n",1000,DEBUG);  
       // sendCommand("AT+CIPSTA=192.168.0.101,192.168.0.1,255,255,255,0\r\n",1000,DEBUG);    // HI اني ضفته  
        sendCommand(stationConCmd, 1000, DEBUG);


        delay(1000);
        sendCommand("AT+CIFSR\r\n",1000,DEBUG);     // get ip address    
    ///
        sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n",1000,DEBUG);  // configure for multiple connections
        sendCommand("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // turn on server on port 80    
    }

    //Make command string for connect to AP
    String make8266InitCommand()
    {         
        String cmd = "AT+CWJAP=\"" ;        
        cmd += mSSID;
        cmd += "\",\"";
        cmd += mPASS;
        cmd += "\"";
        cmd += ",11,0\r\n";

        return cmd;
    }
```

i still can't figure it out

Hope someone can help

Thank you

Comment: you send `AT+RST` immediately after `AT+CWJAP`. it doesn't have time to connect to the new WiFi. with a remembered network it worked, because it connect to the network automatically

Comment: @Juraj how much delay i need to put ?

Comment: @jsotola post updated, please check

Comment: the logic of your sketch is wrong. you throw a bunch of random commands at the AT firmware. it is unclear from your question if you use or want to use the remembered connection or you did turn off autoconnect and want to connect every time etc...

Comment: this is written from a perspective of a library but is valid for raw AT Commands too: https://github.com/jandrassy/WiFiEspAT#persistent-wifi-connection

Comment: @Juraj i updated the question with a new image showing the error, please check

Comment: what is ,11,0 in CWJAP? remove it

Answer (score -1):

If you configure the esp as an access point then it should also be the DHCP server and be supplying ip addresses to it's clients.  Only if you configure it to be a client station itself (eg. connect to your router as client) will it be assigned an ip address.

Comment: what question do you answer here?

Comment: i updated the question with a new image showing the error, please check

Comment: The comment on CWJAP line said it was to configure as access point which made think there was some confusion with wifi network concepts.  However, the error you show occurs right after you try to connect to your ADSL wifi so there is something not right with that network name or password.  Or maybe your wifi AP is doing mac address filtering.